# Use VPN except for some applications in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn

I am a freelancer at Upwork. When I use Upwork's time tracker, if they detect me changing IP a lot, they'd think someone from another place is working using my account and violating their terms.

I am a Web Scraper Specialist, so sometimes I need VPN to work. How can I use VPN but exclude one application (Upwork Time Tracker) from being affected by that VPN? I use Windows 10.

Comment: It's totally different. That's for selected application, mine is for all except for some. It's like addition vs substraction

Comment: Please see the linked article above for the answer. This question has been asked before and answered.

Comment: No, it's the same. Using a VPN for anything except all the applications/OS is the same.

Comment: Glad to help. If I were you I'd check out all the answers on that post, not just the "accepted" on, and the answer that is linked to it as well. There's more than one way to accomplish what you're asking, and there may be some useful information in there.

Comment: Why to close this question if another one does not have the answer anyway?